# Want to assign Date picker component for Row in Ag-Grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I have a Grid in my web page(img attached)
[Grid in WebPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6h5o.png)

[image]

I'm using the below code to format the grid.

```
    const colDefs = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(coalOption)
    .map(propertyName => {
        const columnDefinition: ColDef = {
            headerName: propertyName,
            field: propertyName,
            sortable: true,
            suppressMovable: true,
            width: 120,
        }
        if (propertyName.toLowerCase() === 'parameters') {
            columnDefinition.width = 230;
            columnDefinition.pinned = 'left';
            columnDefinition.filter = 'agTextColumnFilter';
            columnDefinition.filterParams = {
                clearButton: true,
            };
        } else {                   
            columnDefinition.editable = this.isEdit || this.isNew;
            columnDefinition.cellEditorFramework = AgGridNumericCellEditorComponent;
            columnDefinition.cellEditorParams = {
                decimalPlaces:4,
            };
        }
        return columnDefinition;              
    });

    this.defaultColDef = {
        filter: false,
    };
    this.columnDefs = colDefs;
}
```

In this i'm facing the trouble in assigning the Datepicker for Date Column.Because if i set for Column - 1, then the Decimal values in the column get affected.
Actually I have separate Date Picker Component that i commonly used all over the project.I want to use that component here for that specific row Date-1 and Date 2. I'm tired of finding the solutions, but still couldn't get the exact i want. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't really understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to replace the default agDateColumnFilter for the column (so you have a nice date picker for the filter) or do you want to have date picker for each of the date cells to edit their value? Or do you have trouble telling ag-grid how to treat each of the cells in the Column 1?